# Do locally declared lua functions get parsed every time they are passed?

Tags: function, lua

Let's say I have a locally declared function inside another function that gets called a lot:

```
function outer()
    -- Do stuff
    local loop = true
    while loop do -- for some reason
        local function inner()
            -- Do function stuff
        end
        -- Doing stuff
        inner()
    end
end
```

Does the inner function get newly created, parsed, processed, everything, every time it gets encountered at runtime? Basically, is there any performance difference between this pattern and declaring a separate standalone function?

```
function inner()
    -- Do stuff
end

functions outer()
    local loop = true
    while loop do
        inner()
    end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: No.

When you run a Lua chunk (a chunk is usually a file, but sometimes a string), the entire chunk is compiled to bytecode before it is executed. When you define a local function, you are assigning a reference to that function's bytecode to the function's name. Lua does not re-evaluate the function itself.

In your first code snippet, you might get a tiny performance penalty from assigning the bytecode reference to the local variable. Of course, you should benchmark that to be sure. I don't know if Lua can optimize that away.

Note that closures can have different sets of upvalues, but still refer to the same function bytecode.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer that luther has provided, there is a bit more to this, but you can wonder if it is significant. I don't think it will matter a lot in performance.

Lua will compile each function block, however when you use a local function it will have to execute the CLOSURE instruction and a MOVE instruction each time that particular code is called. The MOVE is added to prevent the CALL instruction from popping the closure off the stack. I don't believe Lua optimizes that bit in any case.

If you have a global function or an upvalue, it will only need to acquire that value with an GETGLOBAL, GETTABUP or GETUPVALUE instruction.

You can see the generated bytecode here;
https://luac.nl/s/473abd2a0bb427a31766ea917